# Why didn't some of the previous Buddhas preach the code of discipline?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, buddhas, vinaya

It is said that as some of the previous Buddhas did not set the code of discipline, the Dhamma did not last.

Comment: good question.  i might have read it somewhere too.  Buddha said for next Buddha, Ariyametra, his mind will not be directed towards setting code of discipline for sangha.  IMO, because that time, people will live in perfect 5 precepts and kind heart society.

Comment: You might find this link of interest friend Dewmini: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=bV3shLzx0B4C&pg=RA1-PA169&lpg=RA1-PA169&dq=sariputta+why+do+some+buddha%27s+dispensations+last+long+and+others+are+short&source=bl&ots=UMPmXsIJVM&sig=z8_n376jYdHeQx8M43Mqeekdk8U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVrOiv_YfMAhUi2qYKHRa-ADwQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=dispensations&f=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Vinaya pitaka is preached only if the life span is less than 50,000 years. When the life span is higher, the human world is said to be similar to heavens. The Buddhas usually introduce Vinaya rules when someone commits a misdemeanor. But the people are very virtuous during these times. So the need to introduce new rules does not arise.

Ironically, the Dhamma lasts longer when there's no Vinaya pitaka, due to the much longer life span.

Additional info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_CWFS-rca8

Comment: Hi Sankha, is there a Sutta source for this?

Comment: I would look in the Buddhavamsa.

Comment: So no code of discipline means no five precepts, no eight precepts.... . also?

Comment: @DewminiGunasekera No! They are observed in the society by default. The Buddha doesn't have to mention them specifically.

Comment: So what all Buddhas preached were things like evil actions, meritorious actions,right view/mind etc? As I see what all Buddhas preached is strictly a philosophy. A philosophy with normative statements, not with descriptive statements. Am I correct?

Comment: All Buddhas preach the Dhamma. But not always Vinaya, The Dhamma is what the Buddha understood by direct knowledge. So the word 'philosophy' might not be a good fit for it. The Dhamma consists of both normative and descriptive statements.